# GRE analysis problem

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, gre-exam

I am trying to prove the existence of continuous onto function from (0,1) to [0,1]. Well, it was easy, since $\sin(\dfrac1{x(x-1)})$ does what I need.

BUT... a slight tweak to the definition of continuity grants that the preimage of a closed set is closed. Well, [0,1] is closed, but (0,1) is NOT!

What is wrong with it?

Comment: $(0,1)$ *is* closed in $(0,1)$: any topological space is a closed subset of itself.

Comment: And $(0,1/4]$ is likewise closed in $(0,1)$. Just sayin' ...

Comment: And $(0,1)$ is open **and** closed.

Comment: Just wondering, is there any reason that a simple piecewise function wouldn't work? Take

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}0 & x \in (0, 1/4) \\ 2(x - 1/4) & x \in [1/4, 3/4] \\ 1 & x \in (3/4, 1) \end{cases}$$

because I never would have thought of $\sin(1/(x(x - 1)))$

Comment: Or how about $sin^2(2\pi x)$?

Comment: So why do you say the preimage of a closed set is closed? It seems easy to construct a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f^{-1}([0,1]) = (0,1)$, or am I missing something?

Comment: David K, The preimage of a closed set by a continuous function is closed. You forgot one hypothesis.